# how to use ng-click on a li to hide its ul parent

Tags: angularjs

I have a list refreshing with results in my li elements :

```
<ul ng-init="visible = true" ng-show="visible">
    <li ng-repeat="suggestion in results" 
        ng-mouseover="changeSearchValue(suggestion)" 
        ng-click="visible = false">
        {{suggestion}}
     </li>
</ul>
```

I would like to hide my list (ul) when a li is clicked but i can't make it work... is this a bad way to do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ng-repeat` creates a scope for each iteration, so your `visible` variable from the `ul` element is not necessarily the same one as in each `li` element. Calling the parent scope's variable from the `li` elements should fix it:

```
<ul ng-init="visible = true" ng-show="visible">
    <li ng-repeat="suggestion in results" 
        ng-mouseover="changeSearchValue(suggestion)" 
        ng-click="$parent.visible = false"> <--this is the key
        {{suggestion}}
     </li>
</ul>
```

What you wrote originally would allow you to hide each `li` element separately.

See the difference here: http://jsfiddle.net/oxda3aes/